# set ulimit for non root user

Tags: 18.04, permissions, ulimit

This is for my elasticsearch application, which terminates at startup showing :

```
bootstrap checks failed
[1]: max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65536]
```

I made changes in my limits.conf file for changing `nofile` to 65536 as below:

```
*       soft    nofile  65536
*       hard    nofile  65536
```

and restarted a new session for the same user (non-root user), but when i open a new session first thing i get on my terminal is:

```
bash: ulimit: max user processes: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
```

and my ulimit does not change as well.
What could be the reason? though i am successfully able to change it for root user.

Answer (score 11):

From [here](https://superuser.com/a/1200818/628839) I see that three files have to be changed:

1. `/etc/systemd/user.conf`
2. `/etc/systemd/system.conf`, and
3. `/etc/security/limits.conf`

In the first two add the following line in addition to the changes you made in the third file:

```
DefaultLimitNOFILE=65536
```